# Moveit set_to_pose tuple attribute x issue

Tags: ros, transforms, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help with my attempts to create a pose from my transform listener object. The tf listener is successfully delivering data but my problems begin when I try creating a pose object from the tf data, using the code below:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
  self.tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer)

  rospy.sleep(5)

  try:
    if self.tf_buffer.can_transform('wrist_3_link', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time()) :

      self.transform_stamped = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('wrist_3_link', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time())

      pose = Pose()
      pose.position = self.transform_stamped.transform.translation
      pose.orientation = euler_from_quaternion((
        self.transform_stamped.transform.rotation.x, 
        self.transform_stamped.transform.rotation.y, 
        self.transform_stamped.transform.rotation.z, 
        self.transform_stamped.transform.rotation.w
      ))
    
      self.move_to_pose(pose)

  except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException) as e:
    rospy.logerr(e)


  def move_to_pose(self, pose):
    rospy.loginfo(pose)
    self.manipulator.set_pose_target(pose)
    plan = self.manipulator.plan()
    self.manipulator.execute(plan)
```

Which yields the following error:

```
[INFO] [1552167988.940291, 5.015000]: 
position:    
x: 0.816988026247   
y: -0.109039832758   
z: -0.00443080091744
 orientation: [3.141573333853047, -0.00452701380180146, 3.140211345214987] 

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/sisko/moveit_ws/src/ur5bot_moveit_config/nodes/moveit_goal.py", line 359, in <module>
        TrackBot()   File "/home/sisko/moveit_ws/src/ur5bot_moveit_config/nodes/moveit_goal.py", line 81, in __init__
        self.transform()   File "/home/sisko/moveit_ws/src/ur5bot_moveit_config/nodes/moveit_goal.py", line 115, in transform
        self.move_to_pose(pose)   File "/home/sisko/moveit_ws/src/ur5bot_moveit_config/nodes/moveit_goal.py", line 290, in move_to_pose
        self.manipulator.set_pose_target(pose) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/move_group.py", line 274, in set_pose_target
        ok = self._g.set_pose_target(conversions.pose_to_list(pose), end_effector_link)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/conversions.py", line 54, in pose_to_list
        pose.append(pose_msg.orientation.x) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I been working at finding a solution for hours. I would appreciate the help of a fresh pair of eyes.

UPDATE:
Just including an example of the data from the transform listener.

```
************************* Transform Data: 
[INFO] [1552233229.396174, 6.727000]: header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 6
    nsecs: 701000000
  frame_id: "wrist_3_link"
child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.816964133008
    y: -0.109003488461
    z: -0.00442450622864
  rotation: 
    x: -0.00110212544585
    y: -0.999997191233
    z: -1.36438458498e-05
    w: 0.00209825162089
****************************************
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318105/moveit-set_to_pose-tuple-attribute-x-issue/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2019-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-10**:\

> ```
>  pose = Pose()
> ```

Is `pose` a [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html)? If so, the `orientation` field is already a `Quaternion`, so I'm unsure as to why you are using `euler_from_quaternion(..)`.

Note: a `geometry_msgs/Pose` is almost identical to a [geometry_msgs/Transform](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Transform.html).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-10**:
And minor comment: I don't believe calling methods on an object instance inside its own constructor is recommended/safe (ie: calling `move_to_pose(..)` from `__init__(..)`).

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2019-03-10**:
Hi @gvdhoom.
Thanks for your answer. Regarding if the rotation data is already a quaternion or not, I am not sure.
If a quaternion is an object, the raw rotation data does not seem to be an object.

I included a rospy.loginfo example output of my tf data in my question so you can see what I'm working with.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2019-03-10**:
Thank you @gvdhoom.
I understand your point - finally :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is being caused because you're using euler_from_quaternion. This function converts a quaternion object into a list containing three Euler angles as [described here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/python/transformations.html). As @gvdhoorn pointed out the pose object stores the orientation as a quaternion not Euler angles, so you're altering the data structure which is the cause of the error you posted.

You can simply copy the translation and rotation from the transform object into the pose object, no conversion is necessary. This should solve the problem you're having here.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2019-03-10**:
Hmmm!!!

I feel like such a DOH-nut!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-03-10**:
It happens to us all at times!